# Ruby string not longer than n number of characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is probably something very simple, but is there a way to make a string shorter. Something like:

```
string = "1234567980987654321";
```

From this string above I want only the first 9 characters.

```
new_string = "123456789"
```

Comment: [`String`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html) take a look I am sure you can figure it out :)

Comment: you can just do `string[0..8]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use functionality built into the `String` class.

```
string = "1234567980987654321"

new_string = string[0, 9] #=> "123456798"
```

Comment: @SaraTibbetts it'll output `123456798` .. notice 8 and 9

Answer (score 2):

To add on for Rails (since it was tagged for Rails too),

You can use `String#first`

```
string = "1234567980987654321"
string.first(9) #=> "123456798"
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby or Rails, another way do achieve your result would be by using `range`:

```
string = "1234567980987654321"
new_string = string[0..8] #=> "123456798"
```